# Memory reallocation using mremap

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I am trying to allocate two different 4096 bytes using malloc and initialize these allocations with different values. Afterwards, I want one of the pointers to point to the other allocation "without" changing the value of p1 and "without" copying the data. I want to "remap" the second allocation to the first allocation which should basically change the virtual address in the page table of the process, i.e. no copying is involved. When I run this code, I get that mremap failed. Any idea how to accomplish this?

```
int main(){
    char *p1 = (char *)malloc(4096);
    memset(p1, 'a', 4096);
    char *p2 = (char *)malloc(4096);
    memset(p2, 'b', 4096);
    printf("p1 is %c at address %p\n", p1[0], p1);
    printf("p2 is %c at address &p\n", p2[0], p2);
    free(p1);
    /* remapping virtual addresses */
    void *p0 = mremap(p2, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, p1);
    /* checking */
    printf("p0 is %c at address %p\n", p0[c], p0);
    return 0;
}
```

expected output:
p1 is a at address xxx
p2 is b at address yyy
p0 is b at address xxx

Comment: From the manpage: "If MREMAP_FIXED is specified, then MREMAP_MAYMOVE must also be specified." Is it possible that you need the bitwise & as opposed to |?

Comment: @cecilg23: They are both specified. Bitwise `|` is correct for combining bit flags - bitwise `&` would normally always give you zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The addresses returned by `malloc()` are probably not page-aligned, so `mremap()` is setting `errno` to `EINVAL`. If I use `mmap()` instead of `malloc()`, and fix the syntax errors in your code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(void) {
    char *p1 = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memset(p1, 'a', 4096);

    char *p2 = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                    MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    memset(p2, 'b', 4096);

    printf("p1 is %c at address %p\n", p1[0], (void *)p1);
    printf("p2 is %c at address %p\n", p2[0], (void *)p2);

    void *p0 = mremap(p2, 4096, 4096, MREMAP_MAYMOVE | MREMAP_FIXED, p1);
    if ( p0 == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("mremap: mremap failed");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("p0 is %c at address %p\n", ((char *)p0)[0], p0);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

then I get:

```
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$ ./mremap
p1 is a at address 0x7f5addb71000
p2 is b at address 0x7f5addb70000
p0 is b at address 0x7f5addb71000
paul@local:~/src/c/scratch$
```

Comment: Thanks. Quick question though, how was it possible to remap to p1 before freeing (unmapping) p1 first?

Comment: Because C let's you do all kinds of things. I'm not necessarily recommending this as a good idea, just using `mmap()` as a convenient way to get a page-aligned address.

Comment: hmmm so this basically overrides the page table entry for the virtual page pointed to by p1 to the physical page pointed to by p2. I see. thanks a lot. that was really helpful.

Comment: You *must* remap without unmapping what's there first, unless you have an extreme level of control over every piece of code running in your program. If you unmap first, the address range no longer belongs to you, and you could end up clobbering something else allocated later when you perform the remap.