# Shared memory problem post fork is not getting "shared" (but opens without error)

Tags: c, ipc, semaphore, shared-memory, mmap

I have two processes (result of a fork) that need to share memory between each other. I synchronized read/write into this memory using a semaphore (which works super fine), but when one writes to the shared memory, the other one cannot get the value written. I sure am missing something but I cannot figure out what. I tried to share memory using shmget, shmat etc too without success, so I stayed with shm_open+mmap.

Minimal reproducible example:

#### main.c

```
#include "../headers/pid_handling.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid == 0){
        shm_lock();
        puts("====");
        shm_pid_list * p = shm_get_pid_list_copy();
        printf("Nb of pids : %ld\n", p->number_of_pid);
        shm_add_pid(getpid());
        shm_add_pid(getpid());
        p = shm_get_pid_list_copy();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < p->number_of_pid; i++)
        {
            printf("From %d | %d | %lu\n", getpid(), p->pids[i], p->number_of_pid);
        }
        shm_unlock();
    } else {
        shm_lock();
        puts("====");
        shm_pid_list * p = shm_get_pid_list_copy();
        printf("Nb of pids : %ld\n", p->number_of_pid);
        shm_add_pid(getpid());
        p = shm_get_pid_list_copy();
        printf("%d | %ld\nList of pids: \n", getpid(), p->number_of_pid);
        for (size_t i = 0; i < p->number_of_pid; i++)
        {
            printf("From %d | %d | %lu\n", getpid(), p->pids[i], p->number_of_pid);
        }
        
        shm_unlock();
        exit(1);
    }
    shm_free_shared_memory();
    return 1;
}
```

#### pid_handling.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include "../headers/utils.h"
#include "../headers/pid_handling.h"
#include "../headers/safe_memory.h"
#define SHM_SIZE 4096 * 4 // TODO : properly handle size, might need mremap. Current size is way more than enough to handle PIDs
#define SEM_ID "/SEM_PIDLIST_PRELOAD"
#define SHM_ID "/SHM_PIDLIST_PRELOAD"
#define SEM_INITIAL_VALUE_UNLOCKED 1
#define SHM_KEY_VAL 0x2337B4B3



// see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23668080/memory-reallocation-using-mremap

/*
 * The purpose of this file is to propose a way for logged
 * process to always be able to know its PID and the PID
 * of process it created.
 * 
 * The representation of the memory is defined in the struct shm_pid_list
 * and is composed of the number of pids and a list of those pids.
 */


key_t shm_key = SHM_KEY_VAL;
int shm_id = 0;
int fd_lock = 0;
sem_t* semaphore = SEM_FAILED;
char* shm_ptr = NULL;

/**
 * Creates a shared memory using shm_open and returns the associated file descriptor.
 *
 * @return The file descriptor associated with the created shm. Abort the program if it fails.
 */
int __create_shared_memory(){
    int shm_id = shm_open(SHM_ID, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600);
    if(shm_id == -1) handle_error("shm_open");  
    return shm_id;
}

/**
 * Initialize the shared memory if necessary.
 *
 * @return The file descriptor associated with the created shm. Abort the program if it fails.
 */
void __shm_init_shared_memory(size_t size) {

    // Opens the shared memory. Creates it if it does not exist.
    if( !shm_id ) {
        shm_id = __create_shared_memory();
    }

    ftruncate(shm_id, size);
    shm_ptr = mmap(NULL, size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_id, 0);
    if (shm_ptr == MAP_FAILED) {
        handle_error("mmap shared mem");
    }
    shm_unlink(SHM_ID);
}

void* __shm_get_shared_memory(){
    // If shared memory is not initialized yet, initialize it.
    if(!shm_id || !shm_ptr) {
        __shm_init_shared_memory(SHM_SIZE);
    }
    return shm_ptr;
}

sem_t* __shm_get_lock(){
    return semaphore;
}

void __shm_create_lock(){
    semaphore = sem_open(SEM_ID, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0600, SEM_INITIAL_VALUE_UNLOCKED);
    // File will be deleted upon program termination
    // but is still opened till then (see unlink man)
    sem_unlink(SEM_ID);
    if(semaphore == SEM_FAILED) handle_error("sem_open");
}


/* Note that this also closes the lock */
void shm_free_shared_memory(){
    if(!shm_id) return;

    if(close(shm_id) == -1) {
        puts("could not close fd shm"); 
        return;
    }
    if(sem_close(semaphore) == -1){
        puts("Err closing fd_lock");
        return;
    }
}

void shm_lock(){
    if(semaphore == SEM_FAILED){
        __shm_create_lock();
    }
    sem_wait(semaphore);
    printf("%d locked\n", getpid());
}

void shm_unlock(){
    if(semaphore == SEM_FAILED){
        __shm_create_lock();
    }
    sem_post(semaphore);
    printf("%d unlocked\n", getpid());
}


/**
 * Returns a copied list of pids. The copy is made in order to prevent race condition between
 * a process that would write a new pid to the shm and one that would want to read the list 
 * at a given point.
 * 
 * @return A copied pid_list the caller has to free.
 */
shm_pid_list* shm_get_pid_list_copy(){
    shm_pid_list* p = s_calloc(1, sizeof(shm_pid_list));
    shm_pid_list* shm = __shm_get_shared_memory();
    printf("Getting pid list with %ld pids\n", shm->number_of_pid);
    memcpy(p, shm, sizeof(shm->number_of_pid) + sizeof(pid_t) * shm->number_of_pid);
    return p;
}

pid_t shm_get_pid(unsigned long n){
    shm_pid_list * shm = shm_get_pid_list_copy();
    if(n > shm->number_of_pid) return -1;
    
    return shm->pids[n];
}

void shm_add_pid(pid_t p){
    unsigned long n = 0;
    shm_pid_list* shm = __shm_get_shared_memory();
    n = shm->number_of_pid;
    shm->pids[n] = p;
    shm->number_of_pid++;
    printf("Added pid %d cont is now %ld\n", getpid(), shm->number_of_pid);
}
```

Files `safe_memory.h` contains definitions for s_malloc, s_calloc, s_realloc (which is basic malloc/calloc/realloc with error handling). `utils.h` holds the following:

```
#define handle_error(msg) \
    do { perror(PRELOAD_ERROR msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)
```

The whole thing is compiled using : `gcc main.c safe_memory.c pid_handling.c -lrt -lpthread` (or you could paste main.c in pid_handling.c to avoid having to write .h files).

### Result

```
23539 locked
====
Getting pid list with 0 pids
Nb of pids : 0
Added pid 23539 cont is now 1
Getting pid list with 1 pids
23539 | 1
List of pids: 
From 23539 | 23539 | 1
23539 unlocked
23540 locked
====
Getting pid list with 0 pids
Nb of pids : 0
Added pid 23540 cont is now 1
Added pid 23540 cont is now 2
Getting pid list with 2 pids
From 23540 | 23540 | 2
From 23540 | 23540 | 2
23540 unlocked
```

### Expected result

```
23539 locked
====
Getting pid list with 0 pids
Nb of pids : 0
Added pid 23539 cont is now 1
Getting pid list with 1 pids
23539 | 1
List of pids: 
From 23539 | 23539 | 1
23539 unlocked
23540 locked
====
Getting pid list with 1 pids
Nb of pids : 1
Added pid 23540 cont is now 2
Added pid 23540 cont is now 3
Getting pid list with 3 pids
From 23540 | 23539 | 1
From 23540 | 23540 | 2
From 23540 | 23540 | 3
23540 unlocked
```

I would be glad if anyone would have any idea about why memory write isn't visible from the other process.

Comment: Why don't you just open/attach the shared memory _before_ forking? It's much easier to do it once and inherit it, than to do it twice.

Comment: OK, on reading your code: if the process that first locks the semaphore exits completely before the other process wakes up, won't the shared memory segment be destroyed? If you can't create & inherit it before forking, then whichever process locks the semaphore first needs to _wait_ after unlocking, for the other to attach to the segment. Or you could just attach to the segment before locking the semaphore, so it isn't exclusive.

Comment: You can probably see exactly what is happening by running the whole thing under `strace -f` or similar.

Comment: It is a possibility indeed @Useless. I tried preventing process from exiting (removing `exit(1)` and adding `sleep(5)`), it does not change the result. Also, I cannot open/attache the memory *before* forking. I would have prefer to do it before forking, but I cannot. The purpose of the binary is to be used as a LD_PRELOAD library, thus I cannot predict how the executed program will react. The above code has small chances not to work, but it should be quite reliable.

Comment: So make a 3-way handshake between processes. Whoever gets in first and populates the segment has to wait for an ack from whoever gets in second, keeping the segment alive for the duration.

Comment: This is only possible if I am sure that the preloaded process will fork. It might be a process that never forks. @Useless
My principal problem is the shared memory issue tho, I'll figure out timing details later I think